# How to fix corrupted block in Oracle XE 11g

Tags: oracle11g

Windows Server 2008 R1 32-bit, Oracle XE 11g.

Have a lot of servers with Oracle XE 11g and one of them in such stupid situation. Can't upgrade specific software working using oraDB because of corrupted block in table SYSTEM.DBF doesn't let update DB structure. Tried to restore from backup but all daily cold reserve copies (for several month) include this corrupted block.

XE version doesn't contains BBED. RMAN after connecting and trying uncorrupt block writes that it works only in Enterprise Edition. Restoring from Fast Recovery Area doesn't work, because of log-files contains 96 and 97 instances from 98.

Wanted to transfer tables in clean DB, but there are lot of tables and no ability to connect to DB with dbForge, Toad or SQL Navigator because of corrupted block. Software works well, but need to update version, please, advise me what to do.

Comment: i have no clue how to do it correctly on XE, but would you like to start with block dump? you will see the affected segments and maybe it will be possible to do some manual hack with the block.

Comment: @agent5566 I've found that block with dump, but my release Oracle XE doesn't include instruments to resolve situation. Also select command wasn't work in corrupted DB to transfer information to new DB. In linux there's way to build BBED from repository, but in windows i didn't find such way. So in my situation i've got agree of operator's manager to create new DB, and reconnected service to new DB after operators close requests. After reconfigured backup procedure to prevent emergence of such block - create also hot copy of DB (dump) and send log to e-mail.